# Robot Framework HTML5 - Webdriver support - Webdriver instance of the browser is not able to do login but manually opened browser can

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Robot Framework Version  2.8.3
Selenium2Library Version 1.4

The problem which I am facing is with regards to the controls used in the application under test.
Unlike the conventional coding technique of having the controls with ids, my application has been developed by using 'CSS - Class'.

For example a button is coded as :

where the "btn-do-login" is defined in CSS file.

Here when I enter the ids in the username and password fields, I write Click Element    btn-do-login 
The keyword clicks on the element but does not submits the data to the host as in the case of Submit Form keyword.

Also to mention, the application does not have any form in it. Instead there is a Div with reference to a CSS class.

Following is the entire hierarchy:

```
<div class="login-form">
    <div class="form-element-username"> … </div>
    <div class="form-element-password"> … </div>
    <div id="btn-do-login" class="wbutton-login"> … </div>
</div>
```

Any help on how to Post data to the host is appreciated.

Also, please note that,  now on entering manually the access credentials on this WebPage opened by Webdriver, and trying to submit it manually still gives me the javascript error and the page is not submitted. For logging in the application manually I need to close the browser instance (opened by Webdriver) and open a new instance manually for manual logging.

And Lastly just wanted to ask whether Selenium2Library supports HTML5 ?

This is what I have done till now.

```
>    Login With Valid Credentials   
>>        Input Text     ${id_login_email}    ${country}
>>>       Input Text     ${id_login_password}    ${PASSWD}
>>>>      CLick Element  btn-do-login
```

Here the variables have been defined in separate python files and have been imported as VARIABLE in the setting table.

Thanks in advance.

--Raj Sarodaya

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do User Login
 Input Text    ${LgnLoginEmail}    ${username}
 Input Text    ${LgnLoginPassword}    ${password}
 Click Element At Coordinates    btn-do-login    20   20

Comment: @Harri :  I dont know how to format my comment. Please share you email so that I can email you more details.

Comment: The idea of Stackoverflow is to figure things out in public so others won't have to. So please do not send me emails. Extend your original questions rather than add stuff here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

After doing quite a few trail and errors I was able to make this work.
The problem with submit was that the javascripts were not loading as my system was behind proxy and I had not set the proxy ip in the browsers.

For many other websites proxy was not required contrary to this case hence it took some time for me to correct it.

> :P